# Determining if an element was inserted into a hash map

Tags: c++, hashmap

I'm using Google's [sparsehashmap](http://google-sparsehash.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/sparse_hash_map.html), and trying to work out if a value was inserted or looked up. The following works, but obviously it's looking it up twice. How do I do it without the double lookup?

```
Element newElement = Element();
bool  inserted = ((*map).insert(pair<const int64, Element>(key, newElement))).second;
Element element = (*(((*map).insert(pair<const int64, Element>(key, newElement))).first)).second;
if (inserted)
    puts("INSERTED");
```

I can't check the contents of Element (it's a struct) as I want to differentiate between a default Element being found and newElement being inserted. I couldn't work out how to assign `((*map).insert(pair<const int64, Element>(key, newElement)))` to a variable as it's of a template type that includes types private to the `sparse_hash_map` class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
typedef sparse_hash_map<...>::iterator sh_iterator; //you already have this, haven't you?

std::pair<sh_iterator, bool> res = map->insert(std::make_pair(key, newElement));
if (res.second)
    puts("INSERTED");
```

If, for whatever reason you don't like the `std::make_pair` function, you should consider a typedef for the pair type:

```
typedef pair<const int64, Element> map_pair;
```

Anyway, the return type of `insert` is `pair<iterator, bool>`, and AFAIK `iterator` is a public typedef of the class.

BTW, I don't get why you do the second `insert`... to get to the inserted element? Probably you should declare `element` as a reference. In my suggested code:

```
Element &element = res.first->second;
```

Naturally, if you were using C++11, you could simply do:

```
auto res = ...;
```

Comment: Thanks, the typedef worked great. For anyone else, the line needed is `typedef google::sparse_hashtable_iterator<std::pair<const long unsigned int, Element>, long unsigned int, std::tr1::hash<long unsigned int>, google::sparse_hash_map<long unsigned int, Element>::SelectKey, google::sparse_hash_map<long unsigned int, Element>::SetKey, std::equal_to<long unsigned int>, google::libc_allocator_with_realloc<std::pair<const long unsigned int, Element> > >::iterator sh_iterator;`

Comment: @Alec. But that doesn't make any sense! You should use the very same template arguments used for the map definition. That is, if map is defined as `google::sparse_hash_map<int64, Element> *map;` then the typedef should be simply: `typedef google::sparse_hash_map<int64, Element>::iterator sh_iterator;`.

Comment: Ah, that makes a lot more sense. Thanks @rodrigo

Comment: Also, using element as a reference, should it be `Element *element = &((*(res.first)).second);`?

Comment: @Alec: Well, yes and no. You are defining a pointer, not a reference. But you are right in the second second (!). It should be `Element &element = res.first->second;`. BTW you should avoid using the `*` when a `->` will do (coming from Java or C#, eh?).